# mysql query returns zero rows in SQL query even though it is in the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My mysql queries return zero rows when I try to select a row that I know is in the database(in both phpmyadmin and my php script). when I am in phpmyadmin and try to edit the row it returns the query was successful but returned no rows. Any idea what the problem may? thanks in advance

mysql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `site`.`links` 
WHERE  `links`.`title` =  'Star.Wars.The.Clone.Wars';
```

I know the row is in the data base, I can see it in phpmyadmin

Comment: sure there's no spacing or case difference?

Comment: Are you trying two tables: site & links? "SELECT * FROM `site`,`links` WHERE..." If so, needs to be a comma.

Comment: @Bryan - the database name is site and I think the period is concatenating it to the table which is title.

Comment: #dldnh - I checked the spacing and its all good, and even in phpmyadmin there is an error selecting a title which is really odd to me. I click the edit on the row were it says 'Star.Wars.The.Clone.Wars' and it comes up saying no rows were selected by the query.

Comment: Check if the record really exists. Maybe you are editing a row that is shown due to browser caching that has been deleted in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

What type of column is 'title'?

If it is a CHAR column (versus VARCHAR or TEXT) then it would be padding the column value and you (may, I don't recall) need to include the padding characters when selecting.

Make sure the column is a VARCHAR.

Comment: the type is VARCHAR... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

just a thought. Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  site.links 
WHERE  title =  'Star.Wars.The.Clone.Wars';
```

Also, you may keep the ticks if you wish: `site`.`links`

Answer (score 0):

Try `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `site`.`links` 
WHERE  `links`.`title` LIKE  '%Star.Wars.The.Clone.Wars%';
```

Perhaps there are some spaces that need to be trimmed from your title.